# Where to Place XML File to be Read by Web Part?

Tags: web-part, development, visual-studio, feature

In another question, I finally found a way to deploy the XML file to be read via a Feature, to the _layouts folder:

[Feature Elements File](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47231/feature-elements-file)

Should I be deploying it there at all? I wasn't able to deploy it to my custom Feature folder which was the original plan. Should I be using the _wpresources folder instead?

_layouts is a virtual directory which maps to LAYOUTS? After deployment I was unable to find the file path in code. Where should I deploy the XML file and what is the C# syntax to grab that path?

```
 string path = Page.Server.MapPath("/_layouts/links.xml");
```

This code leads to the following error:

Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\template\layouts\links.xml'

I want to be able to read the links.xml file which is in the virtual "_layouts" directory (currently).

Comment: Why don't you read the file over the network instead of from the file system on the server? You could also consider writing custom values to the web.config instead.

Comment: Re the network, I want the whole thing to be self-contained in a Feature. XML file is a little big and convoluted to stuff into the Web.Config. I just need somewhere to deploy it to and read from it in the Web Part and my knowledge of the virtual paths is limited.

Comment: Why can't you leave it in layouts and use HttpWebRequest to read it in to a stream for your XmlReader constructor?

Comment: Interesting idea... could you post an answer and give me the syntax for finding the path to the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As almost always with SharePoint the answer is it depends.

My criteria would be:

1. Should end-user be able to change the file?
2. If not how many features should use this file?

Depending ot the answers to the questions above pick the appropiate section below

**End-users should  be able to change the file**
Put the file into a document library at the appropiate scope using a `<Module>` in a feature

**File should only be used by a single feature**
Put the file into the feature directory (by marking it as a element file, but not use it in any elements.xml (see below)) and use [SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getgenericsetuppath.aspx) to expand the path to full path

**File cand be used by multiple features**
Put the file into a sub directory of LAYOUTS (using a Mapped folder) and use [SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getgenericsetuppath.aspx) to expand the path to full path

**How to get file into feature folder**
If the file is only used by single web part put it into the Web Part SharePoint Project Item and set Deployment Type to ElementFile like this:
[image]

If it's used by multiple entries in the feature I prefer to create an Empty Element SharePoint Project Item, add the file in there and set deployment type

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "by marking it as a element file, but not use it in any elements.xml"? BTW, the user will not interact in any way with this - only the Web Part which the user cannot alter.

Comment: Description added to answer

Comment: Thanks for the listing of alternatives. It is so nice to hear the comments after the classical "It depends". I appreciate your comments, Per!